# missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing the following code in a angularjs to execute a function and I have missing ) after argument list error .

```
 "content": '<b>DocumentType</b>:'+s.getdocumentTypeName(s.documentType)+'<br><b>Author:</b>'+s.givenName+'</br><b>creationDate:</b>'+ s.dateTimeConverter+'<br><a href="" onclick=\"(getdocByID(' + s.docId + '))\"><b>View Document</b></a>',
```

Comment: There is a syntax error somewhere. But apart from getdocumentTypeName probably needing to be getDocumentTypeName, with a capital D, I can't find the missing closing brace here.

Comment: the problem with the onclick function but I dont no where is the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
"content": '<b>DocumentType</b>:'+s.getDocumentTypeName(s.documentType)+'<br><b>Author:</b>'+s.givenName+'</br><b>creationDate:</b>'+ s.dateTimeConverter+'<br><a href="" onclick="getDocByID(' + s.docId + ')"><b>View Document</b></a>',
```

Try this.

Comment: Not really sure what function name you use, but I try to make them in the same format. hope that can help you.     Upper or lower case really matter in coding, so make sure you use the proper name.

Comment: the problem with the format of the id : when I put s.docId: 6214 it works but the format of the id is like this id:2.16.840.1.113883.2.9.2.0.0.0^703.20170314.151528 it does not work .Idont know how to solve this problem

Comment: when I put this : "content": '<b>DocumentType</b>:'+s.getdocumentTypeName(s.documentType)+'<br><b>Author:</b>'+s.givenName+'</br><b>creationDate:</b>'+ s.dateTimeConverter+'<br><a href="" onclick="(getdocByID(2314))"><b>View Document</b></a>', It works but when I change th id to this : "content": '<b>DocumentType</b>:'+s.getdocumentTypeName(s.documentType)+'<br><b>Author:</b>'+s.givenName+'</br><b>creationDate:</b>'+ s.dateTimeConverter+'<br><a href="" onclick="(getdocByID(2.16.840.1.113883.2.9.2.0.0.0^703.20170314.151528))"><b>View Document</b></a>', It does not working . please any idea

Comment: Try wrap your id with quotation "", you need a better id obviously.